# How to force my script to load after an asynchronous, external script?

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a script that is modifying a Shopify App (Which means the scripts are attached through a third party process and I can't access them.) I want my script to load only after their script is completely finished executing, but I can't figure out what to use to signal this process is complete.

This is my script (currently using setInterval as a stopgap):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var check = setInterval(function() {
        let sprCheck = window['SPR'];
        var spr = $("#shopify-product-reviews"),
            container = spr.find(".spr-content"),
            reviewButton = spr.find(".spr-summary-actions-newreview");

        if (sprCheck) {

            clearInterval(check);

            var reviews = spr.find('.spr-reviews'),
            reviewButtonWrap = spr.find('.spr-summary-actions'),
            form = spr.find('.spr-form'),
            toggleContainer = spr.find('.spr-summary-actions-togglereviews'),
            reviewButtonLabel = reviewButton.text();

            reviewButtonWrap.detach().appendTo(container);
            spr.css('overflow','visible');
            form.detach().insertAfter(reviews);
            if (reviews.children().length) {
                reviewButtonWrap.css('display', 'none');
            }
            toggleContainer.click(function() {
                reviewButtonWrap.toggle();
            });

            spr.fadeTo(300, 1);
            reviewButton.click(function(){
                if (form.is(':visible')) {
                    reviewButton.text('Cancel Review');
                    reviewButton.addClass('spr-close-form');
                } else {
                    reviewButton.text(reviewButtonLabel);
                    reviewButton.removeClass('spr-close-form');
                }
            });
        } 
    }, 300);
})
```

This is where their script is attached:

```
(function() {
  function asyncLoad() {
    var urls = ["\/\/productreviews.shopifycdn.com\/assets\/v4\/spr.js?shop=sukker-sweet-phase-2.myshopify.com"];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = urls[i];
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
  };
  if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
  }
})();
```

This is their script itself:

```
    e = function() {
        "use strict";
        window.innerShiv = function() {
            function n(e, t, r) {
                return /^(?:area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)$/i.test(r) ? e : t + "></" + r + ">"
            }
            var s, o = document,
                d = "abbr article aside audio canvas datalist details figcaption figure footer header hgroup mark meter nav output progress section summary time video".split(" ");
            return function(e, t) {
                if (!s && ((s = o.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<nav></nav>", 1 !== s.childNodes.length)) {
                    for (var r = o.createDocumentFragment(), a = d.length; a--;) r.createElement(d[a]);
                    r.appendChild(s)
                }
                if (e = e.replace(/^\s\s*/, "").replace(/\s\s*$/, "").replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, "").replace(/(<([\w:]+)[^>]*?)\/>/g, n), s.innerHTML = (r = e.match(/^<(tbody|tr|td|col|colgroup|thead|tfoot)/i)) ? "<table>" + e + "</table>" : e, r = r ? s.getElementsByTagName(r[1])[0].parentNode : s, !1 === t) return r.childNodes;
                a = o.createDocumentFragment();
                for (var i = r.childNodes.length; i--;) a.appendChild(r.firstChild);
                return a
            }
        }()
    }, t = {
        exports: {}
    }, e.call(t.exports, t, t.exports), t.exports;
    var e, t;
    (function() {
        window.SPR = function() {
            function n() {}
            return n.shop = Shopify.shop, n.host = "//productreviews.shopifycdn.com", n.version = "v4", n.api_url = n.host + "/proxy/" + n.version, n.badgeEls = [], n.reviewEls = [], n.elSettings = {}, n.$ = void 0, n.extraAjaxParams = {
                shop: n.shop
            }, n.registerCallbacks = function() {
                return this.$(document).bind("spr:badge:loaded", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onBadgeLoad : void 0), this.$(document).bind("spr:product:loaded", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onProductLoad : void 0), this.$(document).bind("spr:reviews:loaded", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onReviewsLoad : void 0), this.$(document).bind("spr:form:loaded", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onFormLoad : void 0), this.$(document).bind("spr:form:success", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onFormSuccess : void 0), this.$(document).bind("spr:form:failure", "undefined" != typeof SPRCallbacks && null !== SPRCallbacks ? SPRCallbacks.onFormFailure : void 0)
            }, n.loadStylesheet = function() {
                var e;
                return (e = document.createElement("link")).setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"), e.setAttribute("type", "text/css"), e.setAttribute("href", "https://productreviews.shopifycdn.com/assets/v4/spr-805222bdeda8199e3a86a468a398e3070e6126868692225ffa23ac7502b1eca2.css"), e.setAttribute("media", "screen"), document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e)
            }, n.initRatingHandler = function() {
                return n.$(document).on("mouseover mouseout", "form a.spr-icon-star", function(e) {
                    var t, r, a;
                    return t = e.currentTarget, a = n.$(t).attr("data-value"), r = n.$(t).parent(), "mouseover" === e.type ? (r.find("a.spr-icon:lt(" + a + ")").addClass("spr-icon-star-hover"), r.find("a.spr-icon:gt(" + (a - 1) + ")").removeClass("spr-icon-star-hover")) : r.find("a.spr-icon").removeClass("spr-icon-star-hover")
                })
            }, n.initDomEls = function() {
                return this.badgeEls = this.$(".shopify-product-reviews-badge[data-id]"), this.reviewEls = this.$("#shopify-product-reviews[data-id]"), this.$.each(this.reviewEls, (a = this, function(e, t) {
                    var r;
                    return r = a.$(t).attr("data-id"), a.elSettings[r] = {}, a.elSettings[r].reviews_el = "#" + (a.$(t).attr("data-reviews-prefix") ? a.$(t).attr("data-reviews-prefix") : "reviews_"), a.elSettings[r].form_el = "#" + (a.$(t).attr("data-form-prefix") ? a.$(t).attr("data-form-prefix") : "form_")
                }));
                var a
            }, n.loadProducts = function() {
                return this.$.each(this.reviewEls, (i = this, function(e, t) {
                    var r, a;
                    if (r = i.$(t).attr("data-id"), "false" !== i.$(t).attr("data-autoload")) return a = i.$.extend({
                        product_id: r,
                        version: i.version
                    }, i.extraAjaxParams), i.$.get(i.api_url + "/reviews/product", a, i.productCallback, "jsonp")
                }));
                var i
            }, n.loadBadges = function() {
                var e, t, r, a, i, n;
                if (0 < (r = this.$.map(this.badgeEls, (n = this, function(e) {
                        return n.$(e).attr("data-id")
                    }))).length) {
                    for (t = 7, i = []; 0 < (e = r.splice(0, t)).length;) a = this.$.extend(this.extraAjaxParams, {
                        product_ids: e
                    }), i.push(this.$.get(this.api_url + "/reviews/badges", a, this.badgesCallback, "jsonp"));
                    return i
                }
            }, n.pageReviews = function(e) {
                var t, r, a;
                return a = this.$(e).data("product-id"), r = this.$(e).data("page"), t = this.$.extend({
                    page: r,
                    product_id: a
                }, this.extraAjaxParams), this.$.get(this.api_url + "/reviews", t, this.paginateCallback, "jsonp"), !1
            }, n.submitForm = function(e) {
                var t, r, a;
                return t = this.$(e).serializeObject(), t = this.$.extend(t, this.extraAjaxParams), t = (t = this.$.param(t)).replace(/%0D%0A/g, "%0A"), this.$.ajax({
                    url: this.api_url + "/reviews/create",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: t,
                    success: this.formCallback,
                    beforeSend: (a = this, function() {
                        return a.$(".spr-button-primary").attr("disabled", "disabled")
                    }),
                    complete: (r = this, function() {
                        return r.$(".spr-button-primary").removeAttr("disabled")
                    })
                }), !1
            }, n.reportReview = function(e) {
                var t;
                return confirm("Are you sure you want to report this review as inappropriate?") && (t = this.$.extend({
                    id: e
                }, this.extraAjaxParams), this.$.get(this.api_url + "/reviews/report", t, this.reportCallback, "jsonp")), !1
            }, n.toggleReviews = function(e) {
                return this.$("#shopify-product-reviews[data-id='" + e + "']").find(".spr-reviews").toggle()
            }, n.toggleForm = function(e) {
                return this.$("#shopify-product-reviews[data-id='" + e + "']").find(".spr-form").toggle()
            }, n.setRating = function(e) {
                var t, r, a;
                return t = this.$(e).parents("form"), a = this.$(e).attr("data-value"), r = this.$(e).parent(), t.find("input[name='review[rating]']").val(a), this.setStarRating(a, r)
            }, n.setStarRating = function(e, t) {
                return t.find("a:lt(" + e + ")").removeClass("spr-icon-star-empty spr-icon-star-hover"), t.find("a:gt(" + (e - 1) + ")").removeClass("spr-icon-star-hover").addClass("spr-icon-star-empty")
            }, n.badgesCallback = function(e) {
                var r;
                return r = e.badges, n.$.map(n.badgeEls, function(e) {
                    var t;
                    if (t = n.$(e).attr("data-id"), r[t] !== undefined) return n.$(e).replaceWith(r[t]), n.triggerEvent("spr:badge:loaded", {
                        id: t
                    })
                })
            }, n.productCallback = function(e) {
                var t;
                return t = e.remote_id.toString(), n.renderProduct(t, e.product_stripped, e.aggregate_rating), n.renderForm(t, e.form), n.renderReviews(t, e.reviews)
            }, n.renderProduct = function(t, r, a) {
                return this.$.map(this.reviewEls, (i = this, function(e) {
                    if (t === i.$(e).attr("data-id")) return i.$(e).html([innerShiv(r, !1), a]), i.triggerEvent("spr:product:loaded", {
                        id: t
                    })
                }));
                var i
            }, n.renderForm = function(e, t) {
                return this.$(this.elSettings[e].form_el + e).html(t), this.triggerEvent("spr:form:loaded", {
                    id: e
                })
            }, n.renderReviews = function(e, t) {
                return n.$(n.elSettings[e].reviews_el + e).html(t), n.triggerEvent("spr:reviews:loaded", {
                    id: e
                })
            }, n.formCallback = function(e) {
                var t, r, a, i;
                return i = e.status, a = e.remote_id, r = e.form, (t = n.$(n.elSettings[a].form_el + a)).html(r), "failure" === i && n.initStarRating(t), "success" === i && (n.$("#shopify-product-reviews[data-id='" + a + "'] .spr-summary-actions-newreview").hide(), n.$(".spr-form-message-success").focus()), n.triggerEvent("spr:form:" + i, {
                    id: a
                })
            }, n.initStarRating = function(e) {
                var t, r, a;
                if ((a = e.find("input[name='review[rating]']")) && a.val()) return r = a.val(), t = e.find(".spr-starrating"), this.setStarRating(r, t)
            }, n.paginateCallback = function(e) {
                var t, r;
                return r = e.remote_id.toString(), t = e.reviews, n.renderReviews(r, t)
            }, n.reportCallback = function(e) {
                var t;
                return t = "#report_" + e.id, n.$(t).replaceWith("<span class='spr-review-reportreview'>" + n.$(t).attr("data-msg") + "</span>")
            }, n.loadjQuery = function(e) {
                return n.loadScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
                    return n.$ = jQuery.noConflict(!0), e()
                })
            }, n.loadScript = function(e, t) {
                var r;
                return (r = document.createElement("script")).type = "text/javascript", r.readyState ? r.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if ("loaded" === r.readyState || "complete" === r.readyState) return r.onreadystatechange = null, t()
                } : r.onload = function() {
                    return t()
                }, r.src = e, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(r)
            }, n.loadjQueryExtentions = function(r) {
                return r.fn.serializeObject = function() {
                    var e, t;
                    return e = {}, t = this.serializeArray(), r.each(t, function() {
                        return e[this.name] ? (e[this.name].push || (e[this.name] = [e[this.name]]), e[this.name].push(this.value || "")) : e[this.name] = this.value || ""
                    }), e
                }
            }, n.triggerEvent = function(e, t) {
                return this.$(document).trigger(e, t)
            }, n
        }(), SPR.loadStylesheet(), SPR.loadjQuery(function() {
            return SPR.$.ajaxSetup({
                cache: !1
            }), SPR.loadjQueryExtentions(SPR.$), SPR.$(document).ready(function() {
                return SPR.registerCallbacks(), SPR.initRatingHandler(), SPR.initDomEls(), SPR.loadProducts(), SPR.loadBadges()
            })
        })
    }).call(this)
}("undefined" != typeof global ? global : "undefined" != typeof window && window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where their script is attached, you could try adding an onload attribute:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.onload = "functionToRunMyOwnScript()"
```

If you can't access the place where it's attached, I personally don't think there's anything wrong with using the interval, as you're currently doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I cannot edit the object that loads the third party scripts :/ My interval method is only working about 80% of the time-- 20% the button is not detached in time and ends up abandoned in its original location. I'm trying to figure out what the absolute latest action performed by the app I can use to initiate my script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options.

1. like you do it (check again and again if the changes are done)
2. use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) , if you wanna go this way, make sure to test this heavly.

To your solution, I think what you miss is a better check (sprCheck). If you say sometimes the function is triggered when the element exists, but is not at the right spot yet, then you also have to check if the element is on the right check before you continue.